# What are the differences between white and brown adipose tissue?

Tags: metabolism

What are the differences between white and brown adipose tissue? Here are some that I have come across:

```
Brown Adipose Tissue                        White Adipose Tissue

Thermogenic                                 Non-thermogenic
Multilocular                                Unilocular
Relatively many mitochondria                Relatively few mitochondria
Vascularised                                Relatively few capillaries
characterized by the presence of leptin     characterized by the presence of UCP-1
```

Comment: I think Shep had more of the right idea in his [answer](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/260/57) to your Meta question about this, I don't know how you can maneuver this to make it more constructive.  In its current form, it's still asking for a list.

Comment: but Kevin's [answer](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/a/269/835) on meta wasn't shot down, so I assumed it would be OK....

Comment: Well, see what everyone else thinks about it, but list questions are normally closed as "not constructive".  Is there anything in particular you are looking for in terms of the relationship between the two types?  That would make a much stronger question and would probably get a better answer, anyway.

Comment: My suggestion was to just ask the question. I didn't think you would answer it in the question.

Comment: Also, BAT is smaller than WAT having 20-40um,30-70um respectively.

Comment: Brown color of adipose tissue is due to cytochrome oxidase.... It's an extra point . I think it will help u in future.....punjab

Comment: there are a lot of differences between brown and white fat (and don't forget beige fat - that's a 'thing' now too) - anatomic differences, physiologic differences, biochemical differences, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking, except to add to the list?

Its worth mentioning that brown adipose tissue is the only organ in the human body whose primary purpose is to generate heat.  We are warm blooded, but the body temperature is regulated by other organs generating heat while they do work (like muscles or I suppose the stomach, kidney, etc).

Brown Tissue is supposed to not a juvenile attribute - doesn't show up in adults to the same extent (usually being limited to neck and upper chest.

Brown Tissue is thought to be present in only critical areas of the body - even in infants.  Its found in the inner body cavity around vital organs.

The color comes from the large number of mitochondria in the cells, which is where the heat is generated via uncoupling protein 1 (UCP1).

White adipose tissue is what we more commonly call fat tissue - its primary function is to store energy in the chemical form of long chain fats.  Fat tissue as it grows can inhibit the function of insulin in the body, increasing insulin resistance.

You could almost call them 'good fat' and 'bad fat'